# Unable to use exclude in rule (error thrown) - webpack 2

Tags: webpack

I get an error for the following rule when I attempt to exclude.

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: { babelrc: true },
                    exclude: [/node_modules/],
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
},
```

The docs say valid conditions for exclude are: strings, regexp, functions, array

But no matter what valid condition I put in exclude I get this error:

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.rules[0].use should be one of these:
   non-empty string | function | object { loader?, options?, query? } | function | [non-empty string | function | object { loader?, options?, query? }]
   Details:
    * configuration.module.rules[0].use should be a string.
    * configuration.module.rules[0].use should be an instance of function.
    * configuration.module.rules[0].use should be an object.
    * configuration.module.rules[0].use should be one of these:
      non-empty string | function | object { loader?, options?, query? }
    * configuration.module.rules[0].use should be an instance of function.
    * configuration.module.rules[0].use[0] should be a string.
    * configuration.module.rules[0].use[0] should be an instance of function.
    * configuration.module.rules[0].use[0] has an unknown property 'exclude'. These properties are valid:
      object { loader?, options?, query? }
    * configuration.module.rules[0].use[0] should be one of these:
      non-empty string | function | object { loader?, options?, query? }
```

If I remove the exclude property it works fine, but I want/need to exclude.

Comment: You have to set `exclude: /node_modules/,` at the same level of test and use.

Comment: Yeah @Hosar is correct. You're including the `exclude` field where it should not be.

Comment: Yep following a bad migration post :(

Answer (score 1):

exclude is on the rule node not on the use node so it should be

```
module: {
rules: [
    {
        test: /\.js$/,  
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
        use: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: { babelrc: true }
            },
        ],
    },
],
```

},